# Custom CollectionViewCell property are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am Implementing Custom Collection View with Custom CollectionView Cell.

Here is my implementation for CollectionView.

```
- (void)setUpCollectionView{
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [self.vwCarCollection setDataSource:self];
    [self.vwCarCollection setDelegate:self];

    [self.vwCarCollection registerClass:[FindMyCarCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FindMyCarCell"];
    [self.vwCarCollection setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.vwCarCollection reloadData];
    [self.vwCarCollection reloadInputViews];
}
```

I called this function on "ViewDidLoad".

Here is my implementation for UICollectionViewDataSource

```
- (UICollectionViewCell  *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    FindMyCarCell *cell = (FindMyCarCell *)[self.vwCarCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FindMyCarCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.vwImgMain.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_car"];
    cell.lblCarNo.text = @"GH2334343";
    return cell;
}
```

When I debug my code, cell instance is there like this

```
<FindMyCarCell: 0x78645b30; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (302 50; 221 180); layer = <CALayer: 0x786a07a0>>
```

But when I tried to update the imageview of my custom cell, it just return that my image view is nil.
What is wrong in my implementation. Could anyone suggest me? Thanks.

Comment: FindMyCarCell *cell = (FindMyCarCell *)[self.vwCarCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FindMyCarCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];  replace   self.vwCarCollection  with collectionView .. then try

Comment: Can you show the method that contains creating `vwImgMain` in `FindMyCarCell` ?

Comment: there is a nice tutorial hear, but it is in swift, but the concepts are similar to obj-c, just go through this http://randexdev.com/2014/08/uicollectionviewcell/

Comment: did you use this cell in storyboard or using separate xib ?

Comment: @KKRocks Yes, I used the the xib to create this cell

Comment: @nynohu. vwImgMain is IBOutlet of my customviewCell and it is public.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some error where you are adding image view to cell. If you have created your cell in Storyboard then don't register your cell class in viewDidLoad. Instead set reuse identifier in Storyboard else add your image view into init with frame method of custom collection view cell class.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Registering programmatically instead of setting the reuse id in the storyboard was causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to call **viewDidApppear**.

```
[self.vwCarCollection registerClass:[FindMyCarCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FindMyCarCell"];
```

Comment: I used separate xib for my custom cell.

Comment: So you need to use `registerNib`, not `registerClass`.

Comment: did you check reuseIdentifier in xib ?

Comment: yes, I used the same identifier like xib. Then I will try with registerNib

Comment: did you use this line in ViewDidAppear ?

Comment: @nynohu, Yeah your solution can solve my problem. I used registerNib instead of registerClass. Thanks u so much all. What is the difference between two of these? :)

Comment: in VIewDidAppear your view fully loaded so.

Comment: Use registerNib when you load the reuseCell from xib file. Use registerClass when you load the reuseCell from class (using code for creating subViews of that Cell). When Cell is created by coding, remember to put all your init view code in `initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`. Just thinking simple.

Comment: @KKRocks I used registerClass in my code. I change it to registerNib according to nynohu's suggestion. Now it works. :) thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xib file, call

```
[self.vwCarCollection registerNib:[UInib nibWithNibName:@"FindMyCarCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FindMyCarCell"];
```

Instead of

```
[self.vwCarCollection registerClass:[FindMyCarCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FindMyCarCell"];
```

The reason is when you call `registerClass`, your `FindMyCarCell`  will be initiallized by calling `initWithFrame`, and you did not implement init your imageView by this way. When you call registerNib, the stack call will initial your `FindMyCarCell` by calling `awakeFromNib` (so the imageView will be created).